# Trying to do some c programming homework and need a bit of guidance

Tags: c

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char ch1 = 'B', ch2 = 'A';
    int result;

    printf("Enter 2 characters without spaces: ");
    scanf("%c%c", &ch1, &ch2);

    result = ch1 % ch2;
}
```

I input `AB` and I cant seem to get the answer or result to come out.

Comment: what do you mean "come out".   This sample code is not printing or returning anything.  I think you should printf the chars your attempting to input and make sure thats working before assuming other things fail.

Comment: You haven't actually told us what you are trying to code up. What is the answer or result that you are expecting? And what is the program doing instead?

Comment: well, it would be nice if you tried to print it, as you print the prompt for it to ask two characters.  Add a `printf("result = %d\n", result);` and you'll se something like `result = 65`

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have just started with C, so in order to get any output, you have to print it using ' printf("..."); ' unless you do that,it will not be displayed by itself.

insert this statement  ' printf("%d",result); '  after  ' result = ch1 % ch2; statement'.